# Count frequency in Pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
     a     b     c        result
0    80    50    10000    pass
1    80    50    10000    pass
2    100   50    10000    pass
3    100   50    10000    fail
...
XX   110   70    15000    pass
XX   110   70    15000    pass
XX   110   80    10000    fail
XX   110   80    10000    fail
```

I want to get the 'pass'-frequency (in %) of each combination (a, b, c) of the dataframe.
For example the above dataset should result in

```
     a     b     c        passFreq
0    80    50    10000    1.0
1    100   50    10000    0.5
...
2    110   70    15000    1.0
3    110   80    10000    0.0
```

If I do

```
df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c']).describe()
```

I get the frequencies but it does not report it back the way I want it and I'm not sure how to retrieve the frequencies and create a new dataset from it.

Any guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) if need percentages for all values of column `result`:

```
print (pd.crosstab([df['a'], df['b'], df['c']], df['result'], normalize=0))
result        fail  pass
a   b  c                
80  50 10000   0.0   1.0
100 50 10000   0.5   0.5
110 70 15000   0.0   1.0
    80 10000   1.0   0.0
```

---

```
df2 = (pd.crosstab([df['a'], df['b'], df['c']], 
                  df['result'], normalize=0)
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df2)
     a   b      c  fail  pass
0   80  50  10000   0.0   1.0
1  100  50  10000   0.5   0.5
2  110  70  15000   0.0   1.0
3  110  80  10000   1.0   0.0
```

If need only `pass` first compare values to new column and then aggregate `mean`:

```
df1 = (df.assign(new = df['result'].eq('pass'))
         .groupby(['a', 'b', 'c'])['new']
         .mean()
         .reset_index(name='pass'))
print (df1)
     a   b      c  pass
0   80  50  10000   1.0
1  100  50  10000   0.5
2  110  70  15000   1.0
3  110  80  10000   0.0
```

Comment: When testing this on my dataset I only need the last paragraph "df1 ...", your code implies that to use df1 I first need to run the crosstab function?

Comment: @RedSmolf - then use only last paragraph solution, `crosstab` solution is if need percentages of call values of column `result`

Answer (score 0):

```py
df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c'])['result'].mean()
```

Comment: This does not work (pandas.core.base.DataError: No numberic types to aggregate)

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the column `pass` and then apply `.mean()` and `.reset_index(drop=True)` to reset index:

```
df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c'])['result'].mean().reset_index(drop=True)
```

If you need `.describe` you can do that too

Comment: This does not work (pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate)